# Clang formatting rule to add an empty line before the closing brace of a struct or class?

Tags: clang-format

I am unable to find a documented way to add an empty line to the end of a class or struct declaration. Is there a way for clang-format to convert this:

```cpp
struct foo {
  int bar = 0;
};
```

To this

```cpp
struct foo {
  int bar = 0;

};
```

And optionally having the ability to add a line to the beginning would be nice as well:

```cpp
struct foo {

  int bar = 0;

};
```

Answer (score 0):

I have found the same problem recently. To add a new line between the class declaration and contents, set `KeepEmptyLinesAtTheStartOfBlocks` to `Yes`.

However, it seems that there is not option to enforce an empty line between last declaration or definition and closing braces.